# How to loop through Dictionary other than using foreach(keyvaluepair)?

Tags: c#

Is there other way to loop through all keys and values other than using

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<T, T> kv in _dic)
```

Comment: What's wrong with `foreach`?

Comment: Call `.ToList()` and iterate over the list indexes?  Get the list of keys and iterate over those to reference the dictionary?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish that you can't do with a `foreach` loop?

Comment: `foreach(var key in _dic.Keys) { var value = _dic[key]; }` doesn't use foreach(*keyvaluepair*)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LINQ expression.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dict.Add("toto","this is toto");
            dict.Add("tata", "this is tata");
            var keys = dict.Where(p => p.Key == "toto"); // LINQ expression is here
            foreach (var key in keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(key);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So `Where` in this context returns `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K,U>>` which you then iterate over with a for each loop. How is this any different from the original for loop which iterated over a collection of KeyValuePairs besides the filter call which was not talked about in the question?

Comment: Curious as to how this is "better" than directly foreaching over the dictionary. This basically boils down to `foreach (var key in (IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>)_dict)` (with an added `if (key.Key == "toto") { continue; }` inside). So still a `foreach` and still a `KeyValuePair`.

Comment: This is just another method. In many cases it is more concise, so easy to read. Moreover it can be chained to other LINQ methods.

Answer (score 3):

I really can't tell why you would want to do this, but...

```
var enumerator = _dic.GetEnumerator();

while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
  var pair = enumerator.Current;
  // ...
}
```

This, of course, is what `foreach` does behind-the-scenes.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through all the Keys, or all the Values as independent lists:

```
foreach(var key in _dic.Keys)
```

or

```
foreach(var value in _dic.Values)
```

I often use the Keys list and reference the dictionary in the loop to get the values.